# Change the value of the Column in a grid in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gxt

I am working on GXT 2.5.5

I have desinged a GRID in a project

In one column of the grid i have render a composite

It looks like this

[image: Grid]

This **Choose evaluation** column is Composite which is rendered in the Grid.

```
public class Evaluation extends Composite {
    private RadioGroup rdgrpEvaluation;
    private Radio radio_1;
        // More radion buttons
    private Radio radio_10;        
}
```

All the **`radio_x.setValue(true)`** in the grid are set from the Model

```
int key = model.get("radioEvaluation");
switch (key) {
    case 1:
         evaluation.getRadio_1().setValue(true);
         break;// more similar code
```

**Now i want that when I click on radio button, the value of the Evalution column should also change.**

Can some body help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that simplest way is call refresh whole table after selecting some button:

```
grid.getView().refresh(false);
```

But you also need to update your model.
When You click on radio button you may set value to your model like^

```
data.setEvalueation(int selectedRadio);
```

Or You can create specified `ValueProvider` to Evaluation column

```
     ColumnConfig<Data,String> evaluationColumn = new ColumnConfig<Data, String>(new ValueProvider<Data>() {
                @Override
                public String getValue(Data o) {
                    String value = o.getRadioColumnValue();
                    return value;
                }

                @Override
                public void setValue(Data o, Data o2) {

                }

                @Override
                public String getPath() {
                    return "evaluation";
                }
            });
```